# Azure search not working with special characters

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a search setup for a list of jobs.
Other than Id field I have just two fields on the search made as searchable and analyzer standard.lucene as following:
[image: config]

And I’m having difficulty to make the search work with things like C# or C++.
 
As per the documentation for unsafe characters we should encode and for Special characters we should scape.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax

But let’s say I want to search all jobs with C# on the title or description I do the following search using the encode %23 and does not seems that I'm getting the correct results. Is returning other jobs that contain only C with other things.
 
[image: result1]

Same way if I want to get only the C++ jobs as per azure docs I should use something like C\+\+ When I tried a got other jobs also.

[image: result2]

So not sure if I’m missing something or did not understand correct the documentation. But I’m not able to get the exact result I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your results depend on the analyzer you use. Read more about analyzers in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers

You can check how your query is analyzed by calling the analyze API with your query and a specified analyzer. For example:

```
{
  "text": "C# engineer",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

Will result in:

```
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "c",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 1,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "engineer",
        "startOffset": 3,
        "endOffset": 11,
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

With the standard analyzer, you effectively no longer have the ability to separate a C# engineer from a C++ engineer. The analyzer will simplify it to two tokens. C. Engineer.

Instead, use one of the built-in analyzers or configure your own. Here is the same example using the whitespace analyzer.

```
{
  "text": "C# engineer",
  "analyzer": "whitespace"
}
```

Results in

```
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "C#",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 2,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "engineer",
        "startOffset": 3,
        "endOffset": 11,
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

**CREATE**

Create the index like this

```
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": true,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Title",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "facetable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "analyzer": "whitespace",
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": [],
        "fields": []
    }
],
```

**UPLOAD**

Test by uploading the following simple content.

```
"value": [
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "1",
        "Title": "C++ Engineer"
    },
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "C# Engineer"
    }
]
```

**QUERY**

Then query

https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/{{YOUR-INDEX}}/docs?search=C%23&$count=true&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version={{API-VERSION}}

Your search for C# now returns the entry with C# in the title.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://walter-searchsvc-we-dev.search.windows.net/indexes('so-73954804')/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.25811607,
            "Id": "2",
            "Title": "C# Engineer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Tks Dan that helps. I will check.