# Azure Cognitive Search - How to search with Reserved Character like &

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am having problem searching document with reserved characters. More specifically i have search string that contains special characters &. But i am not able to read the data from azure search document. Below is the C# code i used to read document from search index.

```
public async Task AzureSearch()
        {
            string searchKey="Rohan_A&F"; 
            SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions();            
            options.SearchFields.Add("CustomerNm");
            options.Select.Add("Id");
            options.Select.Add("CustomerName");       
            options.QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full;
            options.SearchMode = SearchMode.All;   
            
            var client = CreateSearchClient();
            var response = await client.SearchAsync<Object>(String.Format("{0}*",searchKey), options);
        }
```

So not sure if I’m missing something or did not understand correct the documentation. But I’m not able to get the result.

Comment: Can you paste what you are seeing as the result?

Comment: Getting Response status 200 with total count null

Comment: Can you try searching via the search Explorer in the Portal or REST API and see if it gives the same response?

Comment: In Postman I tried with POST 
/indexes/customersearch/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30
Body:
 {  
      "search": "Rohan_A&F"
 } 
I am getting result

Comment: I couldn't see the request body in the above comment. If you are setting queryType: "simple", then please read the following documentation on the simple query syntax to see how to handle reserved characters: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax

Comment: I am using querytype: 'Full' as mentioned in the above  code snippet also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249246/discussion-between-farzzy-msft-and-arshit-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Searching for special characters depend on the analyzer you use. If you just use the standard analyzer, special characters will be removed during indexing. You can use the REST API to test what the standard analyzer does to a string like Rohan_A&F:

```
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "**rohan_a**",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 7,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "**f**",
        "startOffset": 8,
        "endOffset": 9,
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

As you see, the only tokens the indexer keeps is **rohan_a** and **f**. Your question and use case is a duplicate of a recent issue I responded to: [Azure search not working with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954804/azure-search-not-working-with-special-characters/73973559#73973559)

Have a look at the duplicate issue for a detailed write-up on how to use a different analyzer to make searching for special characters work.

Comment: I am able to Retrieve Rohan_a&f but if rohan a&f its not returning response with space
Used Custom Analyzer:
 { "name": "CustomerNm", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true,"retrievable": true,  "sortable": true, "facetable": false,"key": false,"indexAnalyzer": "prefixAnalyzer", "searchAnalyzer": "keyword", "analyzer": null,"synonymMaps": []}

Comment: "analyzers": [{"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer","name": "prefixAnalyzer","tokenizer": "keyword_v2","tokenFilters": ["lowercase"
],"charFilters": []}],"tokenizers": [],"tokenFilters": [{"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2","name": "my_edgeNGram","minGram": 3,"maxGram": 7,"side": "front"}